Is my proof for this case of Rolle's Theorem wrong?
The problem
Suppose $f(x)$ is differentiable over $[0, +\infty)$ and we know that $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$, prove that $\exists \xi \in (0, +\infty)$ such that $f'(\xi)=0$.
my suspecious proof
We can represent $f(x)$ as
$$
f(x)=xf'(\xi), \exists \xi \in (0, x)
$$
take the limit from both side,
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to+\infty}xf'(\xi) = 0
$$
Since $f'(x)$ exists everywhere on $[0, +\infty)$ the limit is rewrriten as
$$
A\lim_{x\to+\infty}x=0
$$
Hence $\exists \xi \in (0, +\infty)$ such that $f'(\xi)=0$, otherwise the limit won't exist.
A counter example?
$$
0 < \xi = \sin x < x, \lim_{x\to\infty}xf'(\xi)=\lim_{x\to\infty}xf'(\sin x)
$$
Is this proof wrong? If so, why? How can we alter it so that it becomes a valid proof?

You find easy proofs for Rolles theorem for example in wiki, to your work: how did you come to “$f()=′()$

(1) What is wrong with the standard proof of the lemma?  Why do you need a different proof?  (2) You lose me at $f(x)=xf'(\xi)$.  What is $\xi$?  Where did it come from?  Maybe you wrote things backwards, and you meant to write "there exists a $\xi\in(0,x)$ such that $f(x) = xf'(\xi)$?   If so, how do you know that such a $\xi$ exists?

Sorry for the order of writing. For $f(x)=xf'(\xi)$, it is from the mean value theorem, $f(b) - f(a) = f'(\xi)(b-a)$ provided f(x) is differenciable on $(a,b)$ and continuous on $[a, b]$, setting $a=0$ and generalizing $b$ to $x$, we get $f(x) - f(0) = f'(\xi)(x-0)$, applying the condition $f(0)=0$, we get $f(x)=f'(\xi)x$.

For why I need a different proof, I don't. I did this just for fun and finding gaps in my knowledge. :P

There is no guarrantee that  $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists. The relation of $\xi$ and the corresponding $x$ in the formula $${f(x)\over x}=f'(\xi),\quad 0<\xi<x$$is not explicit.
I would argue in the following way. If $f(1)=0$ we can use the Rolle theorem. If $f(1)>0$ the value ${1\over 2}f(1)$ is attained once in the interval  $(0,1)$ and once in the interval $(1,\infty),$ by the Darboux property. Thus we can use the Rolle theorem. The same holds for $f(1)<0.$

You are right in that the behviour of $\xi$ isn't explicit as x approches $+\infty$ making it not valid to assert the limitational behavior of $f'(\xi)$. The following argument provided is easy to understand, valid and elegant. Thanks for the answer. $\xi$ isn't bounded by two values having the same limit, so asserting the limitational behavior of $\xi$ when the squeeze theorem is not appliable is not valid.

The conditions that $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}{f(x)}=0$ imply that $f$ is bounded over it's given domain (Why?), and so due to continuity it attains at least one extremal point and the result follows from Fermat's Theorem.

$f(x)=-x(x+1)^{-1}$ attains the maximum at $0$ only.

Thanks for your reasoning. However, if $f(x)=0$ there won't be maximum attained in $(0, +\infty)$. For the example function given by @Szwarc, it does not satisfy the second condition $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$.

@kurodamaria I understand your concern, but if you were to think about it a little bit better, then you'd notice that fundamentally, there's two cases. The case where $f$ is identically equal to the zero function and the case where it doesn't. If it does, then there's nothing left to show. However, if not, then $f$ also attains a global minimum, and so we have two subcases. If $f$ attains it's maximum at zero, then it's minimum is certainly attained at a positive value (given that $f$ is not identically zero). If it doesn't, then we are done.

@RyszardSzwarc The function you've just given me does not satisfy the limit condition.

Right, should be $-x(x^2+1)^{-1}.$

@RyszardSzwarc Still, there's no flaw with my argument. I just didn't provide all necessary details at first. See my previous comment for completeness' sake.

Your proof is fine, but you should replace "maximum" by an extremal point.

@RyszardSzwarc You're right. To be honest, I forgot that exact for some reason. I'm changing right now.
